# Load elements one after another with spinner

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very simpel script that will fade in one element after another. I want to include a loader spinner between those fadeins. I want the spinner to illustrate that something is loading and then hide it and on to the next, sort of like a "message dialog" between two people.

```
$('.int').each(function(index) {
  $(this).delay(2000*index).fadeIn(400);
  // show spinner before fadein and then hide spinner 
});
```

Any suggestions or demos? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opQrdZ

Comment: Looks like you have it sorted already?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What's the problem ? If you need a spinner can't you just fade it in the same way with a lesser delay offset and then fade it out after 2000*index+400 ?